# Show kendo grid title in column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there is a way to represent grid in kendo, so that the title will be in the first column and the data will be in the second column and so on

I want to generate the second grid but I only find the grid is genereted is like the first one 
[image: data 1]

[image: data 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a vertical grid (or a property grid if you want to display a single record) and it ain't supported out of the box by Kendo (as July 2015).  Many components of the grid (like the scrollbars) are hardcoded in Kendo's library and are not made to be modified.  Since the grid source are available, you could, *in theory*, modify the code to create a vertical grid but that would have a lot of impact all over the place and with those changes you can't expect any kind of support from Telerik.

I already requested a vertical grid back in 2012 in [kendo's user voice](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2841182-vertical-grid-property-grid) but Telerik haven't reviewed it yet.

For now, the only simple workaround I can think of would be to pre format your data to invert the columns with the rows.  However, this as some limitations.  For instance, you won't get any header support (filter / sort) nor the virtual scroll support.  If you don't need those support, then you could use the grid to do what you want.